# Explanation of the matrix multiplication using SVD

Tags: matrices, approximation, svd

Trying to understand the Matrix approximation using SVD and watching [ingular Value Decomposition (SVD): Matrix Approximation](https://youtu.be/xy3QyyhiuY4?t=154).

X is represented as the sum of $\sigma_i * u_i \cdot v_i^T$ where $u_i$ is the `i-th` column vector of $U$ and $v_i^T$ is the transposed `i-th` column vector of $V$.

[image]

It is stated in the video that this is because **$\sigma_i * u_i$ is only multiplied by $v_i^T$ column**, but I am confused why.

[image]

## Question

If the operation between $U\cdot\Sigma$ and $V^T$ is the matrix multiplication, then each row element of $U$ as $u_(n)(row)$ should be multiplied by each column element of $V^T$ as in the red?

[image]

Why instead it becomes the multiplication between $u_i$ and $v_i^T$?

Also, the shape of $U$ is `(n, n)` and that of $V_T$ is `(m, m)` where `n > m`. Then how come a column $u_i$ of size `n` can be multiplied by a column $v_i^T$ of size `m`?

Comment: He's using block-matrix multiplication. In general, 
$$
\pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_n} \pmatrix{\sigma_1 \\ & \ddots \\ & \sigma_n} = 
\pmatrix{\sigma_1 u_1 & \cdots & \sigma_n u_n}
$$
and 
$$
\pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_n} \pmatrix{v_1^T \\ \vdots \\ v_n^T} = u_1v_1^T + \cdots + u_nv_n^T.
$$
Note that if $u$ is $n \times 1$ and $v$ is $m \times 1$, then $uv^T$ is a well-defined $m \times n$ matrix, bu $u^Tv$ is not defined.

Comment: $U \Sigma V^T x = U \Sigma \begin{bmatrix} v_1^T x \\ \vdots \\ v_n^T x \end{bmatrix} = U \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 v_1^T x \\ \vdots \\ \sigma_n v_n^T x \end{bmatrix} = \sum_k \sigma_k u_k v_k^T x = (\sum_k \sigma_k u_k v_k^T) x$.